# Increment pointer while copying data

Tags: c

Question, I have a `char*` pointer pointing to some data (say 1kb). I have to call a method in chunk of 32bits current code I have is

```
 char* d;
 boolean r = getData(d); // data will be filled in d
 while (*d != NULL) {
     callAnotherMethod((int) d); // need to call it in chunk of 32 bit
     d = d + 2; // Increment by 2 because its char pointer.
 }
```

What I am not sure about is, its `d + 2` or `d + 1`. I tried it and it works however not sure about concept.

Also If its `int* d`, then whats correct `d + 1` or `d + 2`?

Small update, yes cast to int is intentional because I want to `callAnotherMethod` with 32 bit data.

Comment: It's always just + 1.

Comment: @c1moore Not if it wants to do it in 32-bit chunks.

Comment: Your cast of d to int is wrong, the parameter will get the integer value of the pointer which I don’t think is what you want.

Comment: You have to do callAnotherMethod(\*((int\*)d));

Comment: @Barnar True, I missed that part, but I should clarify.  It's always 1 to increment to the next item regardless of data type (even structs).  To skip multiple items, you increment the pointer by the number of items you want to skip.  To skip 32 bits, you add (32 / 8) = 4.

Comment: You haven't allocated any memory for `d`.

Comment: `getData()` can't change the value of `d`. Function parameters are passed by value, not by reference.

Comment: Do you mean `getData(&d)`?

Comment: @Barmar you are correct ofcourse, I opened my mouth to fast.

Comment: I still don't see how you expect the `while` loop to end. Incrementing a pointer won't get to a null pointer. That's usually the test for looping through a linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char` is generally 8 bits, so to increment by 32 bits you need to increment by `32/8`.

```
d += 4;
```

It would be better to parametrize this in terms of the size of a datatype.

```
d += sizeof(int);
```

You could also just convert the pointer to `int*` and incremented it normally.

```
intd = (int*)d;
while (get_data((char *)intd)) {
    callAnotherMethod(*intd);
    intd++;
}
```

Comment: So its d += sizeof(int)/sizeof(char) correct? And reason is I am copying in 32 bits (int) however pointer is char pointer (8 bit)

Comment: Yes. Why isn't it just an `int *` pointer in the first place?

Comment: getData API is like boolean returnBooleanValue = getData(d) where d is parameter and value is returned in it. This is external function and this is how api is designed.

Comment: If it returns a boolean, how can you assign it to `char *d`?

Comment: Your `while (d != NULL)` loop will never stop. Incrementing a pointer should never result in `NULL`

Comment: @user12087351 you still have an error when calling your other method, your are not passing the value pointed to but the actual adress of the pointer.